When half-elves have children their lives are drastically shortened. What's the formula for calculating it?
A human king had a daughter with an elven lady. The princess, half elf, half mortal, was blessed with a long life, but she was not immortal like her mother. When she grew up, the princess married a mortal prince, and their children were also blessed with long lives, and so did their children after them. But the length of their lives were cut shorter generation after generation until, many years later, the descendants of kings and elves became, once again, mere mortals.
I've already asked for a formula for calculating the rate of decay of this lineage, and the user parasoup answered the question with this formula that I've been using ever since:

$\text{(human-equivalent age)}^{P} = \text{elf age}$
$P = \log_{10}{\text{(elf life expectancy)}} / \log_{10}{\text{(human life expectancy)}} \approx \frac{\log_{10}{\text{elf life expectancy}}}{1.85}$

But now I've found another problem. In this world, the magic sustaining the immortality of elves is finite. When they give birth, they pass down part of their magic to their children, losing it forever. Each time they have a kid their lives are drastically shortened.
So, when the half-elf princess had children her life was cut shorter. She had stayed in the prime of her life many, many years, as if time had forgotten her. She looked barely 20 years old when she had her first son, at the tender age of 150. But after giving birth she suddenly felt older, as if time had finally caught up. She had her second son shortly after, and then another one, and she felt as if the blessing of her elven mother had left her body, along with their children. Alchemist and physicians thought she would live for a thousand years, but she died so much earlier. She had passed down her magic to their children and, in the end, she died like a mortal woman.
She grew old as expected, according to the formula, but when she had her first kid, she started to get old faster, and even faster after her second kid. Let's say she splits her magic in two each time she has a kid. What would be the formula for calculating her life expectancy after giving birth?
Thank you very much. I think I've made myself clear but please let me know if you have any doubt or if I can improve my question.

Just an observation, I'm not saying that the question needs revision at all, but it seems to me that you're applying unwarrantedly precise requirements onto a potentially complex situation. Whilst there's no reason that can't apply in your world if you want it to, it'll look a bit arbitrary to anyone with the background to appreciate it.

@Escapeddentalpatient. This can be attributed to the difference between what the author knows and the reader works out.  If it's for a story, obviously the author would know how it works, but need only say that after giving birth several times, she died at an age much younger than had been expected of her when she was young.

Yeah, that makes sense - part of the mystique of stories. Didn't immediately think of that. Even those written from a naïve perspective (The curious incident of the dog in the night time). @MontyWild

How are elves immortal if they have a finite amount of immortality-sustaining magic?

Would this not in the end work out to be a world full of male elves?

Does anyone on this forum actually publish stories or do they just enjoy doing arcane mathematics?

How are elves immortal at all?  Presumably they give of their own life-extending magic regardless of the genetic makeup of their progeny, or else where does the magic come from?

Let us suppose that the future mother has a life expectancy of $N_1$.  An equivalent human has a life-expectancy of $H$.  So, the mother-to-be's magic gives her $(N_1-H)$ years of extra life.
Let's assume that this extra life is distributed linearly from the age of adulthood at 18 years (Age of Adulthood, $T_A$), so if she was expected to have a lifespan of 1000 years, while an equivalent human is expected to have a lifespan of 90 years (the traditional four-score and ten), the magic is giving her an extra 910 years $(N_1-H)$.
So, at the age of 150 (Current Age, $A_C$), the mother would have used $(A_C-T_A)$ years-worth of her magical life, or $\frac{(A_C-T_A)}{(N_1-H)}$ of it.
Using the OP's example, at 150, before giving birth, the princess would have used $\frac{(150-18)}{910} = 0.145$ or 14.5% of her magical life.
Now, if giving birth splits her magic in two, it would stand to reason that this is her remaining magic... and that her child(ren) get the other half.  (It would be up to the OP if each child of a multiple birth gets half of the mother's magic at the moment of its birth, or if all children of the pregnancy share half of the mother's magic during labour.)
So, if the act of giving birth halves the mother's remaining magical life, $L_R$, after giving birth, she has used $\frac{1-\frac{(A_C-T_A)}{(N_1-H)}}{2}$ of it.  Using the OP's example, this would be $\frac{1-\frac{(150-18)}{910}}{2} = 0.427$, or 42.7%
To calculate equivalent age, we need to solve for Effective Age, $A_E$, where (from earlier) $\frac{(A_E-T_A)}{(N_1-H)} = L_R$.  Solving for $A_E$, we get: $A_E = L_R\times(N_1-H)+T_A$.
Using the example, we get $A_E = 0.427\times(1000-90)+18 = 407$.
So, at the age of 150, the princess gives birth, and becomes effectively the magical age she would have been at 407 if she had not given birth.
To calculate the princess' remaining life, we must consider that the rate at which she is aging is now twice what it was before she gave birth.  This means that her magic was giving her an extra $(N_1-H)$ years, but she has now used $A_C$ years of it: $(N_1-H)-A_C$, and giving birth $N_{Births}$ times (The OP must decide if multiples count as separate births or one birth) has left her with $\frac{1}{2^{N_{Births}}}$ of that remaining magical lifespan: $T_R = \frac{(N_1-H)-A_C}{2^{N_{Births}}}$
Using the example, the princess has $T_R = \frac{(1000-90)-150}{2^1} = 380$ years of her magical life remaining.
Now, if we need to calculate the effect of future births, we obviously need to know the point in the mother's life at which she gives birth, since that affects her remaining magic.  Just living will use up some of the magic, so we can't say how many births these mothers could have without knowing the timing of each birth.
So, if the mother gives birth again $T_B$ years later, she has $T_R=T_R-T_B$ years of magical life remaining, and giving birth again will halve that, so $T_R = \frac{T_R}{2^{N_{Births}}}$
I should note some points:

Normal human women undergo menopause at around age 40, after which further pregnancies are not possible.

I do not know how mortal lifespan is applied to such magical women, whether the years since adulthood are used proportionally to the years of magical life used, or if the magical lifespan sits between the end of adolescence and the onset of mortal aging.

So, I can't say that there will or won't be a point at which the mother's magical age will be such that she can no longer become pregnant, or if once her magical years expire, she will undergo menopause some years later.



Chance to get pregnant decreases drastically at around 40, but that is not because the menopausa. It is because the aging of the internal wall of the uterus. The zygote can not attach to it any more. Period ceases much later, at around 45-55. So very badly are we wired together :-(

I'd say that the age of the elven mother or her "used magical years" should be irrelevant for the calculation. Otherwise even the lives of full blooded elves would become shorter with every generation as both parents have "used" some of their magical years, which would not get passed down to their children.

The aging exponent P is actually made of two parts. The human part and the elven part. The human part is always equal to 1.  and the elven part is what goes beyond 1.
So:
$
P = 1 + P_{elve}
$
I assume that the half-elven princess has a P ≈ 1.7 (Life expectancy of ≈ 1400 years and at 150 years she would be roughly equal to a 19 year old human).
My proposal would be that the elven part loses about 35% of its value with each child born.
$P_{elve-after-birth} = P_{elve-pre-birth} * 0.65$
or after $n$ children
$P_{n} = (P-1) * 0.65^n+1$
this would give for the 150 year old half-elf princess:



number of children
P
human age equivalent at 150
Life expectancy




0
1.7
~19
~1400


1
1.455
~31
~500


2
~1.298
~48
~250


3
~1.192
~67
~161


4
~1.125
~86
~121



As you can see, the third child catapults her to old age and the fourth would probalby kill her.
As the aging catches up rapidly but not instantanous the menopause/aging of the uterus probably needs a few years to set in. That's why she probably was even able to concieve the third child.

Instead of giving some of her years to her childen, half-elfs could give some of their vitality, represented in their slower aging number P (from your age decaying formula).
A common expectation might be that a child would get the middle value of their parents P's, thus (with the human having P = 1) it would get (P +1 )/2. However with the elf magic they are actually getting more (the linked question seems to suggest, that they should get closer to half the years). Then the half elf has to decrease her own P number. Her remaining life expectancy would then be what she would get with her new P number from her current equivalent age on.
Thus as an example: the half-elf has P = 1.66. Then one would expect her childen to have P = 1.33. However they get P = 1.46 instead. Then the half-elfs P would decrease by at least 0.13 per birth. As this is a bit small for her getting in big trouble by the third child let it decrease by 0.3 instead (which then includes some overall lost vitality). After the first child she would then be at P = 1.36. She had it at equivalent age of 20 thus her remaining life expectancy is power(71,1.36) - power(20,1.36) = 329 - 59 = 270 more years. After the second child she has P = 1.06, thus her remaining life expectancy is slightly larger than for a human. After her third child she would be in large problems: she has a P which is smaller than 1, namely P = 0.76. Having this child with e.g. an equivalent age of 23 she would have only about 14.5 years left.
